# Solving a differential equation $\displaystyle \frac{d \alpha}{dt}=w \times\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $\alpha$ be a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{d \alpha}{dt}=w \times\alpha$ for $w$ a constant vector. How can we determine $\alpha$ ?

$\displaystyle w \times\alpha$  : cross product

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with say $\omega=(0,0,1)$ and draw in the plane $z=0$ the vector field $v(x,y,0)=\omega\times (x,y,0).$ Then try to guess an $\alpha(t)$ that starts at this plane and satisfy the DE $\dot \alpha(t)=v(\alpha(t)$. After that take a general $\omega$ and draw (or imagine) the vector field $v({\bf r})=\omega\times {\bf r}$.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do you know how to solve general linear system? $\dot x = A x$?
2. Convert $w \times \alpha$ to $ W \alpha$ where $W$ is matrix associated with [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication).
3. If you have a point rotating around a fixed axis, calculate its velocity.

Answer (score 3):

You can write $w\times\alpha$ as $\Omega\alpha$, where $\Omega$ is an (antisymmetric) matrix. Then the problem reduces to a linear ODE.